# "Pattern syntax in expression context: _" when using map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, tuples

I have this code, which will update (or add) a tuple to a list of tuples conditionally. And I get the aforementioned error

```
updateTuple :: String -> String -> Int -> [Film] -> String
updateTuple userName requestedTitle newRating ((Film title _ _ ratings):restOfFilms)
    | requestedTitle == title = map (\ rating -> if rating == (userName,_) then (userName,newRating) else rating) ratings
    | otherwise = updateTuple userName requestedTitle newRating restOfFilms
```

Comment: The message is quite descriptive: the `_` in `if rating == (userName,_)` makes no sense to me as well as to the compiler.

Comment: so I can't use a wildcard?

Comment: @user3365968 you can't use a wildcard in a comparison, only when pattern matching on the left hand side of a `=` or `->` in a case statement or `<-` in a binding.  What you really should be doing is `if fst rating == userName then ...`

Comment: BTW, the type signature of your function makes no sense: you map ratings list to a list of tuples, while the signature states that your function returns a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this lambda:

```
\rating -> if rating == (userName,_) then (userName,newRating) else rating
```

You're using a wildcard in an expression context, which makes no sense to the compiler, since wildcards can only be used in a pattern match context.

I guess what you intended to do was this:

```
\rating@(userName', _) -> 
  if userName' == userName then (userName,newRating) else rating
```

Answer (score 0):

As @bheklilr and @Nikita Volkov have noted, the problem is here:

```
| requestedTitle == title = map (\ rating -> if rating == (userName,_) then (userName,newRating) else rating) ratings
```

An alternative is to use @-syntax to destructure the `rating` variable:

```
| requestedTitle == title = map (\rating@(ruser,_) -> if ruser == userName then ... else rating)
```

Comment: `| requestedTitle == title = map (\rating -> if fst rating == userName then (userName, newRating) else rating) ratings` I get an error with this, it wants a Char ? @user5402

Comment: @user5402 The problem is that his function's type signature defines a result type as a `String`, while the mapping result is a list of tuples. Since `String` is just an alias for a list of `Char`s, that explains the error he gets.